Azure B2C - Check if existing user during sign up and redirect to log in
We are using a user flow to sign up & sign in users to our application. An important thing to point out is that a single Azure B2C user can represent accounts under different tenants/customers in our app.
e.g. Azure B2C user sample@test.com should be able to login to both customer1/app and customer2/app with their email.
Consider

sample@test.com registers under customer1
some time later, they attempt to create an account for customer2
by default, if they use their email sample@test.com, they will get back a duplicate email error.

What we'd like to do is to first check if our Azure B2C tenant already has the provided email registered and if so, redirect that user to the log in page.
Since I didn't manage to find such a scenario documented, the one potential solution I considered is using "Before creating the user" API Connector
The flow as I envision it then is

sample@test.com registers under customer1
some time later, they attempt to create an account for customer2
API connector's endpoint is hit, detecting an already registered user
At this point, we'd redirect the user to the sign-in page, asking them to log in in their existing account.

Is an API Connector the right tool for the job, is there an alternative approach? I really want to avoid writing custom policies.
I know we can also have an Azure B2C tenant for each customer, but that's also something that I'd prefer to avoid, because it would be a real pain to maintain.

An alternative approach I'm currently considering is the following.
Instead of relying on API Connectors, before redirecting to Azure B2C, we can ask the user for their email. When they submit the form, we can use Graph API to make a request and perform the necessary checks.
When a response is received, it will be easy to tell if we need to run Sign Up or Sign In flow, based on the existing email status.
The flow would then be

Click Sign Up
Ask the user for their email, submit
Use Graph API to perform the check
based on the response, trigger relevant Azure B2C user flow

